# Работа с массивами, удаление элементов, сортировка

Tags: javascript

Дан массив:20,16,15,30,17,21,15

Нужно сделать так чтобы было: 15-17,20-21,30

Т.е удалить из массива повторяющиеся числа, а порядковые числа типа 1,2,3,4,5 заменить на 1-5

Я отсортировал массив и удалил повторящиеся цифры, помогит сделать 1-5, 10-15 и т.д.

---

```js
let arr=[16,15,17,21,20,30,30,15,16,21]

arr.sort((a, b) => a - b)


for(let j=0;j<=arr.length;j++)
{
if(arr[j]===arr[j+1])
    {
        arr.splice(j,1)
    }
   }
alert(arr);
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант. Проходим по отсортированному массиву без дубликатов при помощи `reduce()` и копим последовательные числа в последнем элементе аккумулятора. Когда последовательность прерывается, заменяем этот накопитель на диапазон в строке (или на единственное число, если группа не набралась) и создаём новый накопитель. В конце обрабатываем самый последний накопитель.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const input = fs.readFileSync(0, 'utf-8');
console.log(solve(input));

function solve(input) {
  const arr1 = input.split(',').map(str => Number(str.trim()));

  const arr2 = [...new Set(arr1)] // Убираем дубликаты.
    .sort((a, b) => a - b)
    .reduce(
      (acc, number, index, array) => {
        if (index === 0) {
          acc.push([number]);
        } else {
          const lastGroup = acc[acc.length - 1];

          if (number === array[index - 1] + 1) {
            lastGroup.push(number);
          } else {
            acc[acc.length - 1] = lastGroup.length > 1 ?
              `${lastGroup[0]}-${lastGroup[lastGroup.length - 1]}` :
              lastGroup[0];
            acc.push([number]);
          }
        }

        return acc;
      },
      []
    );

  const lastGroup = arr2[arr2.length - 1];
  arr2[arr2.length - 1] = lastGroup.length > 1 ?
    `${lastGroup[0]}-${lastGroup[lastGroup.length - 1]}` :
    lastGroup[0];

  return arr2.join(',');
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает!
Есть небольшое но, программа должна считывать из стандартного потока ввода входные данные  и выводить ответ в стандартный поток вывода в описанном в условии формате.  Он будет проверен системой на серии тестов. Вот шаблон:
function solve(input)
{
code
}

const fs = require('fs')
const input = fs.readFileSync(0, 'utf-8')
console.log(solve(input))
Здесь подключается модуль fs и используется node js, пробовал сам сделать, но ничего не вышло, слишком сложно для новичка

Comment: @LonelyBear666 А в каком формате будет input? Есть пример?

Comment: без понятия, а какие сущесвуют? Примера нет, в том то и дело

Comment: Трудно без примера. Если предположить, что там просто строка с числами через запятую, тогда можно попробовать, как в последней редакции ответа.

Comment: Окей, пусть будут числа через запятую в input. Вы сможете дописать код Node JS? Чтобы там были readFileSync, writeSync или что-там типо того, чтобы всё зароботало

Comment: Я уже дописал. Этот вариант вызывается так: `node script.js < input.txt`.

Comment: Вы Гений, Ваша измененная конструкция зароботала!

Comment: Вы случайно не ведете курсы по фронт-энду?

Comment: Нет, простите, вообще никаких курсов не веду)

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего оформлять серию, когда начинается новая серия. Примерно так:

```
let startidx = 0;
for (let j=1; j <= arr.length; j++) {
   if (j==arr.length || arr[j]-arr[j-1]>1) {
       if (j-1 == startidx) {
           вывести одно число arr[startidx]
          }
       else {
          вывести серию arr[startidx]-arr[j-1] 
       } 
       startidx = j;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ответ уже дан, но я хочу дополнить. Ваше удаление повторяющихся элементов не совсем верно. Вы можете убедиться в этом, запустив код на массиве

```
let arr=[16,16,16,21,20,30,30,45,90,90,4,15,16,21]
```

Попробуйте

```
for(let j=arr.length-1;j>0;j--)
{
if(arr[j]===arr[j-1])
    {
        arr.splice(j,1)
    }
   }
alert(arr);
```

Дело в том, что `arr.length` уменьшается, когда вы удаляете элемент и до конца вы просто не доходите.

Comment: _до конца вы просто не доходите._ - на самом деле доходит. Длина массива уменьшилась, а счетчик остался тем же. В итоге просто могут пропускаться дублирующие элементы